# Swift : We need to update xmpp message iOS , But we cannot modify as per our requirement

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I am working in a project where I need to integrate XMPP chat. I am using following library to integrate it.

Url : https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios

I need to customize the code for adding features like :

1. Automatic delete message from both ends
2. Image and video sharing

we are unable to modify the code of existing library because we have added the library using pods. Kindly help us to modify the existing features.

I am planning to create extension of existing classes, kinldy let me know If there are other ways to achieve the goal.

Comment: fork and modify it. Then pod"xmpp-messenger-ios", :git => 'https://github.com/YOUR_GIT.git'